# SELECT, GROUP BY and COUNT query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a sample table below,

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------------------+----------+---------------+
| employee_id | first_name  | last_name   | email    | joined_date| title                           | salary   | supervisor_id |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+----------+------------+---------------------------------+----------+---------------+
|         100 | John        | King        | EM1      | 1984-06-17 | CEO                             | 14000.00 |          NULL |
|         101 | Leona       | Kochhar     | EM2      | 1993-09-21 | COO                             | 10000.00 |           100 |
|         102 | Lex         | De Haan     | EM3      | 1992-01-13 | CFO                             | 9000.00  |           100 |
|         103 | Alexander   | Hunold      | EM4      | 2001-04-03 | Gamer                           |  5000.00 |           102 |
|         104 | Dave        | William     | EM5      | 2002-05-21 | Gamer                           |  2000.00 |           103 |
|         105 | David       | Austin      | EM6      | 2002-06-25 | Gamer                           |  2800.00 |           103 |
|         106 | Valli       | Longwind    | EM7      | 2002-02-43 | Gamer                           |  2800.00 |           103 |
```

Certain employees are supervisors to other employees in this table. Do note that supervisor_id is the employee_id.

I am tasked to only use SELECT statement to get the employee_id, first_name, salary of the supervisors and the total number of employee under the supervisor.

In my mind, I know that I will need to use some sort of grouping and count. First, COUNT number of employees under each supervisor and second to GROUP BY supervisor ID. I managed to get the output using the simple COUNT and GROUP BY using this query:

```
SELECT employee_id, COUNT(supervisor_id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY supervisor_id;
```

This output the supervisor_id and number of employees under the supervisor_id. Which is:

```
+---------------+----------------------+
| supervisor_id | COUNT(supervisor_id) |
+---------------+----------------------+
|          NULL |                    0 |
|           100 |                    2 |
|           101 |                    0 |
|           102 |                    0 |
|           103 |                    3 |
```

*Table above slightly modified - this is a sample output

As mentioned, supervisor_id is the employee_id of the employee within the same table. My problem is that I am unable to get this table to display the employee_id, first_name and salary together with the COUNT column. The end result must show the employee_id (linked to supervisor_id), first_name, salary, COUNT.

I have tried this

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary, COUNT(supervisor_id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY employee_id, first_name, salary, supervisor_id;
```

But this just returns the original table.

Also when I tried this

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, salary, COUNT(supervisor_id)
FROM EMPLOYEE
GROUP BY supervisor_id;
```

It returns error "Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column" which according to online is how I craft my query (can't mix aggregated and non-aggregated column?).

Can anyone guide me on this? Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Use the `GROUP BY` in a subquery under the `FROM` then do a `JOIN` in the outer-query.

Comment: This requires a recursive CTE or a recursive stored procedure (if done in the database).  What version of MySQL are you using?  It would also be helpful if you set up a db/sql fiddle of some sort.

Comment: Thanks Dai. Basically I need to JOIN both tables in a single query? @GordonLinoff, I am just running this from CMD prompt. This is actually educational.

Comment: *the total number of employee under the supervisor* means only of the 1st level under the supervisor or on the levels below also?

Comment: I presumed it's the levels below - basically any employee that supervise another person will be included.

Comment: Post your expected output for this sample data and what is your version of MySql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you just need self `LEFT JOIN` here:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/miLeekBXxoiVV1SxuTYc2c/0

```
SELECT s.employee_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, s.salary, COUNT(e.employee_id)
FROM employee s
LEFT JOIN employee e
ON e.supervisor_id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY s.employee_id, s.first_name, s.last_name, s.salary;
```

By the way, you've mentioned in comment that you want to use `HAVING COUNT() = 0`. You should better not use `HAVING` for this purpose but just change this query to `INNER JOIN`. It will do the same but more efficient way. 
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM6q1UyagrZ4e1EHRvJ1NU/0

Comment: Hi this are all in the same table. A JOIN is a must?

Comment: @SunnyBoiz did you try to run the query? yes JOIN is valid to do self join query

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have tried your query and added the "HAVING" clause to filter 0. But I think it's kinda wrong logically - the COUNT should be COUNTING the supervisor_id instead of employee_id. I suppose a change to the COUNT part should be correct? I am trying out Dai suggestions on having GROUP BY in the FROM too.

Comment: @SunnyBoiz It will not be correct. Try to think about `s` alias as supervisors table and `e` alias as `employee` table. So we select all supervisors and then count all employees who report to that supervisor.

Answer (score -1):

Please try this

```
SELECT E1.supervisor_id,count(E2.supervisor_id) FROM `EMPLOYEE` AS E1
LEFT JOIN (select supervisor_id FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY 
supervisor_id) AS E2 ON E1.supervisor_id = E2.supervisor_id
GROUP BY E1.supervisor_id
```